# Call custom function from excel in C# Program

Tags: c#, excel, vba, com, interop

I have an excel addin (*.xla) that contains many complex functions that all take input parameters and return values.  I unfortunately cannot create a *.XLL as I don't have access to the *.xla file.

I've managed to use C# to write the excel function into a cell (as a string), calculate the cell, and then retrieve the result back into C#.  This method works but it feels very ad hoc and inefficient.

Given the situation described above, is there a better way for calling a custom excel function (that takes parameters) from C#?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the excellent Excel-DNA to build a C# XLL that uses xlfEvaluate to invoke the UDF defined in the .xla? MSDN doc for xlfEvaluate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687913.aspx. You can pass in any string that can appear in a worksheet cell. So it shouldn't be too difficult to code some C# to compose the name of the VBA function and some parameters into a string and then pass them to xlfEvaluate.